# Rails: ajax/remote form submits every time any element with a button tag is clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I just noticed it last night and have been up since then trying to figure out why it's doing this. I have an ajax/remote form that responds to js. When I click on any element with a button tag wrapped around, my form submits it's. Any idea as to what's going on here?

---

Some code: (I have buttons that popup when hovering via over certain words with jquery but the problem existed prior to adding them)

```
<%= semantic_form_for(@post, :html => {:multipart => true, class: "form-vertical"}, :remote => true) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= f.text_area :description %> <!-- a li list of 4 horizontal buttons popup when hover -->

<button class="btn-save"> <!-- found out I didn't even need the input submit button -->
    <span>Save</span>
</button>
<% end %>

#posts controller
# GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  # PUT /posts/1
  # PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update_attributes(post_params_update)
        flash.now[:notice] = "successfully updated!"
        format.html { redirect_to edit_post_path(@post), notice: 'successfully updated!' }
        format.json { render json: edit_post_path(@post), status: :created, location: @post }
        format.js 
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

I even tried removing all the rest of my js files.. still the same

Comment: Could you be so nice and paste some code?

Comment: Are you always using `submit_tag`s?

Comment: @MrDanA I'm pretty sure I don't have a submit_tag anywhere in my app

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel sorry --  just edited in some of my code. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add type="button to your button tag(s) if you don't want the form to submit when clicking the button.

```
<button type="button">...<button>
```